# static resources not found when mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to beutify the url so I have created the following .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

#RewriteRule ^target/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?target=$1
RewriteRule ^quienes-somos$ index.php?target=about
RewriteRule ^el-equipo$ index.php?target=equipo
RewriteRule ^a-quien-va-dirigido$ index.php?target=dirigido
RewriteRule ^programa-integrativo-para-directivos$ index.php?target=pid
RewriteRule ^modulos-especificos$ index.php?target=modulos
RewriteRule ^espacio-empresa$ index.php?target=empresa
RewriteRule ^espacio-individual$ index.php?target=individual
RewriteRule ^trabajo-bioenergetico$ index.php?target=bionergetico

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?target=$1
```

Everything looks fine when request:

```
http://inside.amimusa.org/modulos-especificos
```

but when request is:

```
http://inside.amimusa.org/modulos-especificos/
```

the page is not found.

I added a new line to .htaccess to allow the ended slash as follows

```
 RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [L]
```

and

```
http://inside.amimusa.org/modulos-especificos/
```

works but the static resoruces are not found:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://inside.amimusa.org/modulos-especificos/js/sweetalert.min.js"
sweetalert.min.js
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://inside.amimusa.org/modulos-especificos/css/sweetalert.css"
sweetalert.css
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://inside.amimusa.org/modulos-especificos/js/sweetalert.min.js"
sweetalert.min.js
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://inside.amimusa.org/modulos-especificos/css/sweetalert.css"
```

I tried to add a new rewrite rule as:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/js/(.+)$ /$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/css/(.+)$ /$2 [L]
```

but it seems to not be the trick.

Anybody could help?

Answer (score 1):

This do the trick:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/js/(.+)$ /js/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/css/(.+)$ /css/$2 [L]
```