# remove everything but domain name from url

Tags: rewrite, url

I am looking if the is an easy way to keep the webpage always with the URL like:

```
http://example.com
```

at the time there are request like

```
http://example.com?target=dirigido
http://example.com/a-quien-va-dirigido/
http://www.example.com/a-quien-va-dirigido/
...
```

behind.

Anybody could help?

*EDIT*

The following rule

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=permanent]
```

seems to lose the ?target=dirigido request.

*EDIT2*

The case is the site is a single-page-application in which I load the needed html file by a a jquery load function. They recently asked me to add a carrousel with a link to the different parts of the site, so I added a request param

```
?target=<content>
```

and I load the correspondant content.

I added some rules to make beutify urls

[static resources not found when mod_rewrite](https://serverfault.com/questions/723564/static-resources-not-found-when-mod-rewrite)

But when the user goes to:

```
http://inside.amimusa.org/el-equipo
```

firstable it's fine, but since the page it's a single-page application, when he/she navigates throght the menu, he/she is really going to, let's say

```
http://inside.amimusa.org/programa-integrativo-para-directivos/
```

but in the address bar it keeps: http://inside.amimusa.org/el-equipo what is awful.

So I was thinking to make all the site works hidden everything under the domain, but the request have still to work.

Comment: No. The URL has to reflect the page that has been loaded. Otherwise how is the web server going to know what to serve? It will just serve the default page every time. I really don't know what you're trying to get at here. There is one way to do this, which would be a single page application all done in javascript, but even they usually use hashed URLs.

Comment: I'll clarify the scenario by editing the question. Thanks

Comment: If your application relies upon the URL or a GET request to function properly, then it can't be made "beautiful". If it relied upon session cookies or a POST request, you could have your way.

Comment: I've changed everything to one request by click. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Apache:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com [L,R=permanent]
```

The initial match (`^.*$`) can be all sorts of things. I chose one that does give you access over the request URI via `$1`, should it be necessary.

If you simply want to make sure everybody uses the same domain and rewrite all to one, use:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !=domain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$         http://domain.com$1 [L,R=permanent]
```

Comment: I lose the request, it keeps requesting index.php without the target.

Comment: That's exactly what you asked for. I'l update my answer.